# Why do I keep getting the error s is not defined?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on a homework problem and it keeps returning the same error. Here is the problem 
Write a function named "json_average" that takes a JSON formatted string as a parameter in the format of an array of objects where each object has keys "mass", "density", "temperature", and "velocity" and each key maps to a floating point number. This function should return the average "velocity" of all the objects in the array as a JSON string in the format {"velocity": }

I tried switching things around like using let s = 0 and var = 0, either way it's still not working. Here is the code I tried.

```
function json_average(x) {
    let data = JSON.parse(x);
    var s = 0 ;
    var n = 0; 
    var a;
    for (let i of data) {
        a = i["velocity"];
        s = s + a ;
        n = n + 1 ;
    }
    let d = {"velocity" : (s/n)};
    return(JSON.stringify(d));
}
```

When I submit the code this is what it returns.

```
`error on input ['[{"mass": 3.55, "density": 380.72, "velocity": 33.11, "temperature": 46.8}, {"mass": 91.37, "density": 572.04, "velocity": 64.43, "temperature": -0.13}, {"mass": 40.4, "density": 124.52, "velocity": 52.8, "temperature": 38.81}, {"mass": 68.92, "density": 326.77, "velocity": 31.64, "temperature": 43.71}, {"mass": 3.22, "density": 419.85, "velocity": 70.64, "temperature": 23.58}]']:` 
ReferenceError: s is not defined
```

Comment: `let s = s + 1;` introduces a new uninitialized variable `s` which you try to add 1 to. Read up on what `var` and `let` actually do.

Comment: You already declared s and n variable before loop using var. Inside for loop block you declared again using let, which is accessible only within for loop block. You need to understand scopes in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use s when it is not initialized. Updated the function, hope this helps.

```js
function json_average(x) {
    let data = JSON.parse(x);
    var s = 0 ;
    var n = 0; 
    for (let i of data) {
        let a = i["velocity"];
        s = s + a ;
        n = n + 1 ;
    }
    let d = {"velocity" : (s/n)};
    return(JSON.stringify(d));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining already declared variable inside a loop to have block scope (in loop). Variables declared with let inside a block is no accessible outside the block scope. Also if you want to give s and these other variables block scope in te loop you will not be able to get its value outside the loop for calculating velocity. See js fiddle.

```js
function json_average(x) {
    let data = JSON.parse(x);
    var s = 0 ;
    var n = 0; 
    for (i in data) {
        a = data[i]["velocity"];
        s = s + a ;
        n = n + 1 ;
    }

    let d = {"velocity" : (s/n)};
    return(JSON.stringify(d));
}

var result = json_average('[{"mass": 3.55, "density": 380.72, "velocity": 33.11, "temperature": 46.8}, {"mass": 91.37, "density": 572.04, "velocity": 64.43, "temperature": -0.13}, {"mass": 40.4, "density": 124.52, "velocity": 52.8, "temperature": 38.81}, {"mass": 68.92, "density": 326.77, "velocity": 31.64, "temperature": 43.71}, {"mass": 3.22, "density": 419.85, "velocity": 70.64, "temperature": 23.58}]');

console.log(result);
```